# Bounded linear functionals on $L^\infty$.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am looking at a practice final and I am a bit confused by this statement I am trying to prove:

"There is a nonzero bounded linear functional on $L^\infty([0,1])$ which vanishes on the subspace $C^0([0,1])$."

[Edit: for the sake of clarity of what the comments were about, I'm leaving this paragraph:] I am used to working with $C^0(\mathbb R)$, but I am assuming that $C^0([0,1])$ is the set of bounded functions on $[0,1]$ which vanish at the endpoints. Now, the only such map I can think of (I am afraid to call it a functional, as it cannot be obtained by integrating against a $L^1$ function) is the Dirac delta at $0$.
I was hoping there would be a way to prove the existence of the functional implicitly.

[Edit: new idea.] Ok, so to apply the fact that by a Corollary of the Hanh-Banach theorem, there exists such a functional, I need to show that $C^0$ is a closed subspace. This is equivalent to having any Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset C^0[0,1]$ converge to a continuous function in the $L^\infty$ norm.

Comment: Are you sure $C^0[0,1]$ isn't the space of continuous functions on the unit interval? The notation is standard, and they are all measurable and bounded.

Comment: The space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity is usually denoted $C_0(X)$, with the $0$ as a subscript. $C^0(X)$, with the superscript is often used for the space of continuous functions, in keeping with $C^k(X)$ being the $k$ times continuously differentiable functions, $C^0(X)$ is the space of functions all of whose derivatives up to and including the $0$-th are continuous.

Comment: @Potato Yes, I do, but it tells us that if we have a functional on a subspace, there exists a norm-preserving extension, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, thanks! I'll think about it that way, and see if it helps.

Comment: @wiiza Hahn-Banach does also other things. It tells you that for every closed and convex subset $A$ and every $x\notin A$, there is a continuous linear functional separating $A$ and $x$. If $A$ is a linear subspace, how can a linear functional separate $A$ and $x$?

Comment: @wiiza, I deleted my answer. It wasn't useful.